# Django filtering odd behavior with for loop

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to perform some filtering in Django, and trying to test how long it takes with different backend structures. The filtering is working, however, when I try to get the average time that filtering takes through running it n (set to 1000) amount of times, then dividing total time it takes by n, it is around 10x faster, then when n is set to 1. Is there a reason for this? (I am multiplying by 1000 to convert to ms)

without average:

```
    temp = Response.objects.filter(id="Asde22dFee")[0].content
    end = time.time()
    return HttpResponse((end-start)*1000)
```

with average:

```
    
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1000):
        temp = Response.objects.filter(id="Asde22dFee")[0].content
    end = time.time()
    return HttpResponse((end-start)*1000 / 1000)
```

Comment: Multiplying and dividing by 1000? That's just one. Since there are only two values (start and end), to find out average you need to divide by 2 regardless of what `n` is.

Comment: well, that would make sense, however I am trying to find the average time to calculate the "temp" variable... so need to divide by the num of times it is calculated...

Comment: Secondly, average isn't calculated by subtracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calculating average the wrong way.

The formula for finding average is this:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n
___________________
        n
```

Now, if you want to find the average time for doing `n`-number of queries, you'll have to measure actual time taken (i.e. `end - start`) by each query, then add all the *times* and divide by `n`:

```
times = [] # list for holding all the times

n = 1000

for i in range(n):
    start = time.time() # start time for query
    temp = Response.objects.filter(id="Asde22dFee")[0].content
    end = time.time() # end time for query

    time_taken = end - start # time taken by the query
    # put this into the times list
    times.append(time_taken)

return HttpResponse(sum(times) * 1000 / n)
```